# How to print a list of maps with each map entry in a seperate line

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I want to print a array list, in that array list it contains hash map and I print in a text file. while trying to print the text file it print in single line. I need in a separate line
Example:

```
ArrayList<Object> mainlist= new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) 
{   
    hmap.put("key1", "03-08-2018");
    hmap.put("key2", "xyz";
    hmap.put("key3", "123");
    //ArrayList USed:::
    mainlist.add(hmap);
    mainlist.add("\n");
}
return mainlist;
```

I return in text file. It generates a single line but I need separate lines in my output text file.

Expected output in text file:

```
[{key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123}
 {key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123}
{key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123}
]
```

Actual output in text file:

```
[{key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123},{key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123},{key1=03-08-2018,key2=xyz,key3=123}]
```

Can any one help me to out of this?
Thanks for ur reply

Comment: Don't just output the result of `toString()` but rather take that result and format it the way you want. Like, replace the `,` with a line break character.

Comment: I am not getting can u please explain it more

Comment: you simply call `toString` on the list it seems, that, what you see is the default output of the list.
You need to iterate through the list and print the information what you and how you like

Comment: How are you dumping into a text file? Can you share the code?

Comment: Thank you its working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it's working for me. How Are you writing it to file?

I did it like this:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/test/outputXXXX.txt");
    ArrayList<Object> mainlist= new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        hmap.put("key1", "03-08-2018");
        hmap.put("key2", "xyz");
        hmap.put("key3", "123");
        //ArrayList USed:::
        mainlist.add(hmap);
        mainlist.add("\n");
    }
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path))
    {
        writer.write(mainlist.toString());
    }
```

And output in file:

```
[{key1=03-08-2018, key2=xyz, key3=123}, 
, {key1=03-08-2018, key2=xyz, key3=123}, 
, {key1=03-08-2018, key2=xyz, key3=123}, 
, {key1=03-08-2018, key2=xyz, key3=123}, 
, {key1=03-08-2018, key2=xyz, key3=123}, 
]
```

EDIT:
Sorry, didin't see you need it without comma.

You can do this like that then:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/test/outputXXXX.txt");
    ArrayList<Object> mainlist= new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        hmap.put("key1", "03-08-2018");
        hmap.put("key2", "xyz");
        hmap.put("key3", "123");
        //ArrayList USed:::
        mainlist.add(hmap);
        mainlist.add("\n");
    }
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path))
    {
        writer.write("[");
        for (Object o : mainlist) {
            writer.write(o.toString());
        }
        writer.write("]");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply: I got the same output in console and I didn't get in text file

Comment: In console it print what we expected but not in text file.  it still print in single line

Comment: Can you show your all code? Because it's working for me :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply it working fine while I opening in notepad++

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Object> mainlist= new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) 
{  
   hmap.put("key1", "03-08-2018");
   hmap.put("key2", "xyz"); //you missed closing paranthesis here
   hmap.put("key3", "123");
   //ArrayList USed:::
   mainlist.add(hmap);
   mainlist.add("\n");
}
return mainlist;
```

You can try the below code in :: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayListExample{
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Object> mainlist= new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {  
        hmap.put("key1", "03-08-2018");
        hmap.put("key2", "xyz");
        hmap.put("key3", "123");
        //ArrayList USed:::
        mainlist.add(hmap);
        mainlist.add("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(mainlist);  
    return;
    }
}
```

This gives your expected output. Hope this helps you.
Thanks.